# Output tests to browser with Karma

Tags: javascript, testing, karma-runner

I am using Karma to test my project and can see tests passing an failing in the console window, however, how do I get these to show in the browser?  The browser only has a green bar (even though a test is failing) with

> Karma v0.10.2 - connected

Written in it.

I have tried addong `singleRun :false` to the karma.config.js file.

The config file looks like this:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '../',

        files: [
            'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
            'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js',
            'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
            'app/js/**/*.js',
            'test/unit/**/*.js'
        ],

        autoWatch: true,
        singleRun: false,
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        plugins: [
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine'
        ],

        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
            suite: 'unit'
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 7):

[matthias-schuetz](https://npmjs.org/~matthias-schuetz) wrote a plugin that claims to produce html test output.

https://npmjs.org/package/karma-htmlfile-reporter

Along with the instructions on the plugin page I had to include a reference to the plugin in the Karma config -

```
plugins: [
'karma-htmlfile-reporter'
]
```

Comment: Seems to have a bug with plugins attribute overriding devDependencies. Once I added all the dependencies to the plugins attribute ('karma-jasmine' and 'karma-chrome-launcher') I stopped getting errors at startup but results are as per karma without the plugin.

Comment: I had some trouble with the plugins also - No Provider for framework Jasmine - once I commented out the plugins entry it worked

Comment: This only outputs the results to a file, not into the window running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to [Documention](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html), even not very perfect:

If 'singleRun' is false, it will set the ci-mode on, so, make it true, and you will see some failed red status on the top bars of browers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to do this with Karma.
The "best" way to solve this problem would be to hunker down and write a html-reporter for karma (which would make a lot of us other Karma users very happy).

If this is too much work for you, the second best thing is to use the junit reporter which generates an xml file. You can then post-process the xml file in some way that turns it into a HTML-file which you can then view in your browser

Comment: I recently published `karma-code-reporter` to npm. if someone would test it I'll be very happy :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to display [HTML5 Web Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) with Karma so I wrote something quick to get it to work with Karma version 0.11. Might behave slightly different with other versions. I load this script in with the rest of my application scripts, it will store the karma test results and after completion it will determine the success of the test and then reset to the original karma functions so they're not changed when this script gets run again.

```
// store all my test results
var results = [];
// Wrap the karma result function
var resultFunc = window.__karma__.result;
window.__karma__.result = function(result){
    // run the original function
    resultFunc(result);
    // push each result on my storage array
    results.push(result);
}

// wrap the karma complete function
var completeFunc = window.__karma__.complete;
window.__karma__.complete = function(result){
    // run the original function
    completeFunc(result);
    // determine success
    var success = results.every(function(r){ return r.success });

    if (success) {
        // display a success notification
    }
    else {
        // display a test failure notification
    }

    // reset the result function
    window.__karma__.result = resultFunc;
    // reset the complete function
    window.__karma__.complete = completeFunc;
}
```